# Error 403 "Access not configured" writing to bucket using JSON API

Tags: java, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to write to Cloud Storage with the REST API using this code:

```
  public static void insertData() {
                try {
                    StorageObject st = new StorageObject();
    //create the media object
                    Media m = new Media();
   String content = "hi! this is a test";
                    m.setData(Base64.encodeBase64String(content.getBytes()));
                    m.setContentType("text/html");
                    st.setMedia(m);
    //this gets me the credential, works for other APIs but not cloud storage
                    Storage storage = RequestBuilder.buildStorage();
                    //Create the insert and execute
                    Insert insert = storage.objects().insert("mybucket", st);
                    insert.execute();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    log.severe(e.getMessage());
                }
            }
```

This is my ACL entry as per the REST API:

```
 "kind": "storage#bucketAccessControls",
 "items": [
  {
   "kind": "storage#bucketAccessControl",
   "id": "gammeprediction/allUsers",
   "selfLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1beta1/b/gammeprediction/acl/allUsers",
   "bucket": "mybucket",
   "entity": "allUsers",
   "role": "OWNER"
  }]
```

This is how I get the credential:

```
private static Credential authorize() {
        GoogleCredential credential = null;
        //load properties
        Properties appProperties = new Properties();
            appProperties.load(RequestBuilder.class
                    .getResourceAsStream("/app.properties"));

        // creates an authorization with the key and service account given
        InputStream is = RequestBuilder.class.getResourceAsStream("/"
                + appProperties.getProperty("app.keyFileName"));
        PrivateKey pk;
        try {
            pk = PrivateKeys.loadFromKeyStore(KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12"),
                    is, "notasecret", "privatekey", "notasecret");
            credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
                    .setTransport(HTTP_TRANSPORT)
                    .setJsonFactory(JSON_FACTORY)
                    .setServiceAccountId(
                            appProperties
                                    .getProperty("app.serviceAccount"))
                    .setServiceAccountPrivateKey(pk)
                    .setServiceAccountScopes(PredictionScopes.PREDICTION,
                            DriveScopes.DRIVE, StorageScopes.DEVSTORAGE_FULL_CONTROL).build();


        return credential;
    }
```

The permissions on the bucket are OWNER for allUsers, but I still get a 403 Forbidden "Access not configured" error. What could possibly be wrong?

Comment: When you say OWNER, do you mean FULL_CONTROL? I believe `owner` is automatically set to the group ID for project owners. (see https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/accesscontrol)  Can you share the actual ACL on the bucket? You can get this with `gsutil getacl gs://mybucket`.

Comment: Another thing to try would be to use gsutil to do an upload test to ensure your permissions are correct.  If it works, we can focus on the java code, and if it doesn't, we should focus on the permissions.

Comment: I don't use gsutil but the api explorer to set ACLs. I'll try with the gsutil, but I think it is set right.

Comment: Also I am able to write to the bucket using the Java API, but I want to migrate to REST API for interoperability

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once the JSON API is generally available, this logic will work.

However, at the moment, the JSON API is in Limited Preview. Since an unknown user is not considered to be a member of the limited preview, completely anonymous queries via the REST API are currently not possible. Instead, you must provide at a bare minimum a whitelisted API key when you connect. If you provide no further identity information, you'll be treated as an anonymous user. Or, going further, you can use OAuth2 credentials instead to be treated as a registered user. For more, see: https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/

Is that a GWT RequestBuilder? I'm not entirely familiar with its use, unfortunately. If it helps, here's an example of setting up a connection with an API key using the Google API Java Client: https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/OAuth2#Unauthenticated_access

Also, it looks like your call to setData() is passing a non-base64'd string, which will fail.

Comment: I am using a service account to access it. This works with other APIs I'm using, (prediction and drive). Will try the Base64 though... I'm adding the requestbuilder code

Comment: Ok, after some corrections I arrived to the "Access Not Configured" message, which I suppose means I don't have access to the Limited preview... I'll request it!